# Initial value generator in a circuit (Anfangswertgenerator)

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, impedance, laplace-transform

I am preparing for my electrical engineering exam and I saw this in my script.
I have this first circuit and the requirement is to **draw the circuit in Laplace with initial value generator where t > 0**
Below that is the solution provided by the professor, but I only have the photo as a solution and not an explanation. I do not understand why is it there and how it is used. What does it mean?
Can someone please explain it to me or tell me how is it called in English so I can search for more literature? Thank you.

Initual circuit:

[image: Initial circuit]

Solution provided:

[image: Solution circuit]

Comment: [Related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/506056)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it has a specific name. See slide 24 of this [resource](https://www.ius.edu.ba/sites/default/files/u772/ee202laplacetransform.pdf#page=24).

Consider an **inductor** with inductance \$L\$ and an initial condition \$i_L(0) = i_0\$. The differential equation describing its behaviour is

$$v_L(t) = L \frac{d\ i_L(t)}{dt}$$

Applying Laplace transform,

$$V_L(s) = L (s I_L(s) - i_0)$$

A person given only the above equation, if asked to draw the component or circuit corresponding to it will say that above equation corresponds to a circuit which looks like the diagram below (from the mentioned link)

[image: Laplace domain inductor]

The figure shown in the question is just the source transformed version of the same circuit (it is also shown in the mentioned link).