# 2nd Order Differential circuit convert to Laplace domain

Tags: laplace-transform

The circuit is closed At t = 0 , initial state of capacitor v(0-) = 1v and inductor i(0-) = 0A.

My problem is when I convert this circuit into Laplace domain resistor become 2 and inductor become S. What happen to capacitor.

Please give an advice.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Where's your differential equation?

Comment: @Andyaka I didn't write differential equation because if I can directly this circuit convert to Laplace domain then capacitor, inductor become resistors so then easily I can use KVL to Laplace domain circuit but I don't understand to convert capacitor with initial state.

Comment: Write Laplace equation first, without replacing values. this can help you.   https://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/analyze-an-rlc-circuit-using-laplace-methods/

Comment: The impedance of a capacitance C is 1/(sC) in the frequency domain.

Comment: @Chathura1 Are you supposed to solve this as a time domain result? Looks like it to me. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you

Comment: See if one my [previous answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/506056) helps.

Comment: @Chathura1     Have you seen and understood how to include "initial conditions" ? Ok. Edit and add your Laplace equation  in the question.

Comment: I have posted an answer at https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/284017 which you may find helpful.Also take a look at this:https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/284074 In order to solve a RLC circuit depending on the damping there are some formulas you need to know,you dont have to do it by hand every time

Answer (score -1):

To take into account the initial voltage of a charged capacitor, only add this voltage (Vo/s, **of course**) as a additional serial source (with capacitor) in your circuitry.

[image]

Here is an illustration what happens in 3 similar problems. At time only framed in green.

[image]